# Keep using tensors created before using tf.reset_default_graph()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to tensorflow/tensorboard, and I'm trying to figure out how to use them.
I created a simple graph which adds up a few constants, say something like

```py
a = tf.constant(10.0)
b = tf.constant(50.0)
sum = a + b
```

and visualizing it in tensorboard by

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('test_graph/')
writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
writer.flush()
```

everything ok so far, the graphs are correctly visualized.

If I use tf.reset_default_graph() and I open tensorboard again, as expected I got the message:

```
Graph visualization failed: the graph is empty....
```

At this point, I tried simply to run:

```
sum_new = a + b
```

so, basically I'm defining sum_new by using the tensors a and b I created before resetting the graph. I don't get any errors, because a and be are still existing in memory. However, if I open tensorboard, I still get the error message about the graph being empty.

Why is this happening? If I create a graph and then delete it, is there any way to keep using the variables defined before the reset in a new graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`tf.reset_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reset_default_graph) it simply, well, resets the default graph to a new [`tf.Graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) instance. TensorFlow keeps a singleton graph object that is the default one, and resetting it means that any new operations created in the default graph will be on a different graph than before.

However, that does not mean that the previous default graph is deleted. In fact, graphs cannot be deleted, other than losing every reference to it (so basically when you cannot obtain a reference to the object by any means). In your example, you have `a` and `b`, which are two tensors produced by operations in the first default graph, let's call it `g1`. After calling `tf.reset_default_graph()`, the default graph is now `g2`, and it is empty. However, `g1` still exists, and you can actually get a reference to it with `a.graph` or `b.graph`. If you do `writer.add_graph(a.graph)` you will be able to see it in TensorBoard.

Now, what happens when you do `sum_new = a + b` after resetting the default graph. In general, we would assume that a new addition operation is created in the default graph, which is now `g2`. However, it doesn't work exactly like that. In fact, if we tried to do that, TensorFlow would complain, since `a` and `b` do not belong to `g2`, but to `g1`. What happens is that when TensorFlow makes a new operation it looks at its arguments, and makes the new operation in the same graph as them. So with `sum_new` a new addition operation would be created in `g1` again. As I said, you will be able to see it if you write `a.graph` to TensorBoard.

Interestingly, if you do `sum_new = a + 20.0`, it would still work, and create a new constant operation (for the `20.0`) and an addition in `g1`. However, if you do `sum_new = a + tf.constant(20.0)`, then it finally fails. The `tf.constant(20.0)` is created in the new default graph `g2`, and when you try to operate it with `a` it fails because the tensors belong to different graphs.

A potentially relevant takeaway from this is that `tf.reset_default_graph()` does not necessarily delete and frees the memory from the previous default graph, so if you have very heavy graphs that you want to delete (which it's not too common I think, since memory is usually spent by sessions), make sure you get rid of every reference to it (in this case, for example, you could do `del a, b`).